# Does Python make a system call to get the current time?

Tags: python, operating-system, context-switch

If I get the current time using either:

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

or,

```
time.time()
```

Does it make a system call to get the time? Or does the Python process have its own time service that is called to get the time?

The reason I am asking this question is to understand whether Python has to make a context switch to get the current time. Because if it makes a system call to get the current time, then that's quite an expensive operation. But if it has its own time service that, then the operation is not as expensive.

Comment: It's almost certainly an OS call.  It doesn't necessarily have to be expensive, however.

Comment: Yes, it makes a system call. However, if you are worried about the overhead of a context switch, Python is probably not the right language for your task. You realize that a Python program is executed by an interpreter processing Python byte code, right?

Comment: Getting current time is such a standard thing, common sense suggests it will be optimized to highest extent. If it's an academic question, then I don't know the exact answer, but if it's a practical one, I suggest using it freely without doubts. I can guarantee it won't cause any bottlenecks.

Comment: Unlikely if you run linux: [Why don't Linux utils use a system call to get the current time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316074/why-dont-linux-utils-use-a-system-call-to-get-the-current-time). However this is OS and version dependent. AFAIK all modern OSes will have means to get some clock time without the expensive context switch, otherwise it would impossible to get clocks with better tham millisecond precision I think.

Comment: For example on my machine: `$ strace -e trace=time,gettimeofday python3 -c 'import time;time.time()'
+++ exited with 0 +++
$ strace -e trace=time,gettimeofday python3 -c 'import datetime;datetime.datetime.today()'
+++ exited with 0 +++`. So no syscall is recorded.

Comment: What would or could be “its own time service”?